# Is it memory efficient to first create string and then add it to vector through move semantics or to create element in vector?

Tags: c++, string, memory, vector, move

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("");
v[0] += 's';
v[0] += 't';
v[0] += 'r';
v.push_back("");
v[1] += 's';
v[1] += 't';
v[1] += 'r';
```

and

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::string s = "";
s += 's';
s += 't';
s += 'r';
std::string s1 = s;
v.push_back(std::move(s));
v.push_back(std::move(s1));
```

In first case we first create element in vector and then modify it. I suppose in such small case there will be enough memory reserved in first place, but if it's not - will be vector `v` contiguous in memory, or just pointers to string objects? Does adding an element to string element in a vector makes last one to perform memory reallocation?

In second case, will be memory allocated for strings used as rvalue an added directly into allocated somewhere vector without memory reallocation for strings?

Comment: You can write your code with a custom allocator that logs its operations and see for yourself!

Comment: Re the title: in a word, “yes”.

Comment: Even with move semantics the destination string still has to be initialised. So you're initialising two strings vs initialising one string. What do you think?

Comment: Note that `std::string` may not necessarily be cheap to move due to small string optimization. Whether that has any real performance impact on your program or not is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` always stores data in a contiguous block of memory.
In both cases if the `string`s You want to push back can't fit in the
already allocated memory, there will be reallocation.

By doing `v.push_back(std::move(s))` the data will be moved to the `std::string` in the `vector`
from `s`, so the unused copy of `s`'s data won't remain in the memory.
This can be more efficient for large amount of data, but in Your case this
won't make much difference.

In the second case You also have to initialize two more `string`s...

Comment: Very important to note that only the string objects are stored contiguously in the vector, not the heap memory used for the actual string data. (There is of course short string optimizations that store short strings internally to avoid heap for short strings, though)